# How to send a portion of the requests to another url

Tags: java, spring, netty, webfiltering

I have a web service which handles GET/POST/PUT HTTP requests using a Spring Rest Controller (using Netty and not Apache Tomcat). I wish to filter all the requests coming in my service, and when a request has a certain header configured, I want to send this specific request to a whole different URL, while returning the response to the same entity which sent the original request.

Here is my code:

```java
@Component
public class MyWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyWebFilter.class);

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
        HttpHeaders headers = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders();
        if (headers.containsKey("someHeader")) {
            if (someService.askSomething(Objects.requireNonNull(headers.get("someHeader")))) {
                URI originalUri = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getURI();
                log.info("Redirecting request with URI {} to some service", originalUri.getPath());
                try {
                    URI someUri = new URI("http",
                            originalUri.getUserInfo(),
                            someService.getHost(),
                            someService.getPort(),
                            originalUri.getPath(),
                            originalUri.getQuery(),
                            originalUri.getFragment());
                    ServerHttpRequest newRequest =  serverWebExchange.getRequest().mutate().uri(someUri).build();
                    ServerWebExchange newExchange = serverWebExchange.mutate().request(newRequest).build();
                    return webFilterChain.filter(newExchange);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        }
        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
    }
}
```

With this implementation the request is simply passed through to my normal rest controller and does not reach the other service. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved this by using Spring's WebClient (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-webclient) in order to resend the request to the external service.

```
 @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
        HttpHeaders headers = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders();
        if (headers.containsKey("someHeader")) {
            if (someService.askSomething(Objects.requireNonNull(headers.get("someHeader")))) {
                URI originalUri = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getURI();
                log.info("Redirecting a {} HTTP request with path {} to some service",serverWebExchange.getRequest().getMethod(), originalUri.getPath());
                return sendToSomeService(serverWebExchange.getRequest(), originalUri.getPath()).flatMap(body -> writeResponse(serverWebExchange, body));

            }
        }
        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
    }

    public Mono<String> sendToSomeService(ServerHttpRequest request, String path) {
        return this.webClient.method(Objects.requireNonNull(request.getMethod())).uri(path)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(request.getBody()))
                .headers(getHttpHeadersConsumer(request))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
    }

    @NotNull
    private Consumer<HttpHeaders> getHttpHeadersConsumer(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        return new Consumer<HttpHeaders>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> header : request.getHeaders().entrySet()) {
                    httpHeaders.set(header.getKey(), header.getValue().get(0));
                }
            }
        };
    }


    private Mono<Void> writeResponse(ServerWebExchange exchange, String message) {
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        return exchange
                .getResponse()
                .writeWith(
                        Flux.just(
                                exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add @Order and specify correct order, and then set debug = true to see the filter execution.
see also [spring webflux webfilters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.reactive.webflux.web-filters)

Comment: I don't think this has to do with order. I've debugged it and the request reaches the filter properly. I'm trying to figure out how to send it onwards to an external service instead of the service it was sent to originally, while sending the response back to the original sender.